# PHPTAL -Trying to get property of non-object while using macros

Tags: php, phptal

I am using PHPTAL 1.2.2 
Template page is template.tpl

```
<form>
        <div tal:repeat="field fields">
                <tal:block tal:define="name repeat/field/key" metal:use-macro="${field/type}" />
        </div>
</form>

<tal:block metal:define-macro="text">
        <label>${field/label}</label><input name="${name}" type="text" value="${field/value}" />
</tal:block>

<tal:block metal:define-macro="select">
        <label>${field/label}</label><select name="${name}">
                <tal:block tal:repeat="value field/valuelist">
                        <option tal:condition="php:field.value != value" value="${value}">${value}</option>

                </tal:block>
        </select>
</tal:block>
```

And my php page is

```
<?php
  require_once 'PHPTAL.php';

  $fields = array(
    'name'   => array('label'=>'Name','type'=>'text','value'=>'Test User'),
    'user'   => array('label'=>'Age','type'=>'select','valuelist'=>array(1,2,3),'value'=>2) ,

    );
   $t = new PHPTAL('tempalte.tpl');
   $t->fields = $fields;
 try {
        echo $t->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }

?>
```

I was getting an error in ie as "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Windows\Temp\tpl_4d6be820_formonline1__HAfMCyjTSQl6RgUTRjXcHA.php on line 24"

But in firefox and chrome it works fine but i view source there was lot of html code in it other than that tag.

Comment: Try forcing the tal template not to cache and see if it will work at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such PHP errors only happen inside `php:` prefixed expression, so it's probably about `php:field.value`. See if `field` is an object. If it's an array, then you need `php:field['value']`. If it can be NULL, then you need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me when I concatenated a string to my echo statement. The variable is assigned.

```
   if($des != NULL)
            echo '<p><a href="javascript:rightgroupnav()">'.$des->name.'</a></p>';
```

This line works in Chrome and Firefox. But not Internet Explorer. I tried also to teste it in this way

```
<p><?=$des->name?></p>
```

This works, and I hope you can find it helpful. Does anyone know why they seem to parse data differently?